# CSS Rounded corners in IE

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you do CSS rounded corners in IE without using images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142876/can-you-do-css-rounded-corners-in-ie-without-using-images)

How can I get rounded corners in CSS with IE?  I have this right now...

```
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: This has been asked to death, try searching.

Comment: what version of ie?  i believe 9 has it, 8 does not.

Answer (score 2):

Not with only with CSS, well unless you include IE javascript behaviors.  You can use css3pie but I would consider it a hack to get it to work in IE and sometimes glitchy.
http://css3pie.com/

You could use jQuery not that jQuery is required. http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

You could do it with background imagse [rounded corners IE and background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362379/rounded-corners-ie-and-background-images)

You can do it in ie9
[How to write CSS3 rounded corners for IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427276/how-to-write-css3-rounded-corners-for-ie9)